# removeAttr('style') only works randomly

Tags: jquery, css, attr

I call the following on a bunch of objects when the current slide leaves my jcarousel container:

```
$.fn.removeAnimation = function() {
    var o = $(this);
    o.stop(true, true).removeAttr('style');
}
```

$(this) refers to a bunch of objects which are present on the slide such as h2, h3, p, img etc.

Oddly though if I keep cycling back and forth on the slides the styling doesn;t get removed from some of the elements. It is really random too on which elements are affected here.

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Do you have an example page? I cannot guess what is wrong.

Comment: Try using `.removeProp` and for more details check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr ... If that didn't work, try `this.style = ''`

Comment: Maybe this is related to your problem: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9699